# How to dump video bios of Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)

Tags: fedora, intel, intel-graphics

I am trying to set up a Windows 10 virtual machine with Virtual Machine Manager and have been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTX10QlFJ6c) tutorial to set up GPU passthrough with only one GPU. I am doing this on a Dell Inspirion with an Intel UHD Graphics 620 integrated GPU. Part of the tutorial has me insert `<rom fIle='vBiosRom.rom'/>` into the XML config of my virtual machine, but I can not find the ROM file for my GPU anywhere online. I have been trying to dump the video bios ROM using these commands:

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/rom
cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/rom > vbios.dump
echo 0 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/rom
```

but keep getting `cat: '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/rom': Input/output error`. I tried doing this again in recovery mode in case it wasn't working due to the GPU being in use, but I got the same error and `Invalid PCI ROM header signature: expecting 0xaa55, got 0xffff`. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Boot into Windows, use GPU-Z.

Comment: That would require me to install windows which I am trying to avoid by setting up this VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is most likely booting in UEFI mode.
Reboot into your BIOS setup and switch from UEFI to legacy boot.
Then try and dump the vBIOS again. You can switch back to UEFI afterwards.

PS: Your OS may fail to boot after switching to legacy boot, so I recommend you you create a live disk of Ubuntu or whatever you prefer and use for the dump.

This may help [How to dump video BIOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KN5pkSWX4IM)

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked, and I was finally able to dump the BIOS. Now I need to figure out why my VM isn't booting.